# Error: INSERT INTO MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

my code:

```
<?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$database = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if (!$conn) {
   die("failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "connect<br>";

$sql = "INSERT INTO test2 (1, 2, 3) VALUES ('1', '2', '3')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
   echo "add";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

i got error:

connect
Error: INSERT INTO test2 (1, 2, 3) VALUES ('1', '2', '3')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1, 2, 3) VALUES ('1', '2', '3')' at line 1

how to fix it?

Comment: Where is no question, there is no answer.

Comment: What's your question? Are you trying to insert one row? Multiple? Are you trying to reference named columns? You haven't shown any code (which is why I removed the `php` tag). Just a lone error message. Please edit your question with more specifics.

Comment: So the names of your columns are `'1'` `'2'` and `'3'`? And according to that error, you have a double quote `"` before the first `1`?

Answer (score 1):

If you name your columns using only numbers, then you'll have to use backticks around them, e.g. to quote them. See the official chapter [Identifier Names](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/identifier-names/), which states:

> **Further rules:**
>
> Identifier names may begin with a numeral, but can't only contain
>   numerals unless quoted.

So, correct would be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test2 (`1`, `2`, `3`) VALUES ('1', '2', '3')";
```

Or, if the columns are of type INT (or similar):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test2 (`1`, `2`, `3`) VALUES (1, 2, 3)";
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first set of parentheses, '1', '2', '3' are expected as column names. I'm thinking you intended these to be values instead.

Comment: How about waiting for clarification (I already asked about this exact thing, in a comment)? Right now, the OP has shown *zero* effort, and *zero* code.